# Flutter background service for android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to fetch the users' current location when they start an activity on the app until they choose to stop it.

Location works fine but when the app is closed or minimized, the program stops.

This code was not running in the background.

In manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In receiver file

```
package beczone.app.android.one

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.ConnectivityManager 

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

class NetworkChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val cm :ConnectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager;
        var flutterEngine:FlutterEngine = MainActivity.flutterEngine;
        val methodChannel:MethodChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "app_service") 
        methodChannel.invokeMethod("onNetworkStatusChange", (cm!=null&&cm.activeNetworkInfo!!.isConnected));
 
    }
}
```

In flutter

```
class AppService {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('app_service');

  static void listen(void Function(bool isConnected) callback) {
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      switch (call.method) {
        case "onNetworkStatusChange":
          final bool isConnected = call.arguments;
           //hear is action
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what the heck is "android.intent.action.ALL" ? this is all wrong ... most broadcast receivers are not working when registered in manifest since API 26  - you need to register them from code ... just use some package which already doing this(recomendation for library is off-topic - so ill not provide one)